# Android align image in top and center in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm trying to align image to top of my Relative Layout and after that center it horizontally. Here is the code I'm using for :

```
<ImageView  
        android:id="@+id/collection_image_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  />
```

,but this code is not working. My image is centered,but not aligned at top of my Relative Layout. I tried with `android:scaleType="fitStart"`, but it's actually align imag left and top of it's parent.

So any idea how I can align the image correctly as I need?

P.S. I forget to mention that I'm setting the image to my `ImageView` like this :

```
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inTempStorage = new byte[8*1024];

    ops = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cis,null,o2);
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.collection_image_background);
    view.setImageBitmap(ops);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

code seems to be perfect except content area you had assign `fill_parent` takes whole view and will appear as center, so just modify it by `wrap_content`

```
  <ImageView  
            android:id="@+id/collection_image_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  />
```

Comment: It's ok, but I want to image to fit at least on width to it's parent.

Comment: you can do by android:layout_width="fill_parent" and android:layout_height="wrap_content".

Comment: actually i set now both width and height to `fill_parent`and it worked...have no idea why it wasn't working before when i didn't touch anything else in the code. thanks anyway for the answer!